# Using Imputer with conditions on the cell values of columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, knn, imputation

I have a data frame with certain number of 'nan' in certain columns:
(Total number of rows is over 50000)

Data looks something like below (showing for 1st 3 columns)

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 5 | . | . | . |
| **nan** | 54 | 10 | . | . | . |
| 23 | **nan** | 9 | . | . | . |
| 30 | 32 | 6 | . | . | . |
| 20 | 22 | **nan** | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . |

There is a condition on these columns : A < B and A > C always for all rows.

I wish to use some imputer (preferably KNNImputer) such that after imputing the above conditions are satisfied.
(while applying imputer in a generic way, it turns out that many cells are not satisfying these conditions)

How can this be implemented?

Comment: I don't think we can do that using any framework available. You have to have a `else` statement. I mean, if KNN Imputer doesn't fill those NaN values according to your conditions, then what else should we put there?

Comment: the thing is knn is fitting these.. but the conditions are not always satisfied.. in that scenario, we will need to explicitly replace such 'filled' cells with some conditions such as cell(A) = min(cell(A), cell(B)) for all rows...but, was wondering about efficacy of this and if there is any other better way..